# TypeError Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined` for the following line of code: `this.error = error.code;`

Here's what I'm trying to do (it's in an Angular Reactive Form, calling a web service):

```js
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  // More declarations...
  error: string | null; // I also tried error = '' and error = null
  // Constructor, etc.

  public submit() {

    this.error = null;
    if (this.signUpForm.valid) {
      // Create an Auth0 user
      this.authService.signUp(this.signUp.value.email, this.signUp.value.password, this.authServiceCallback);
    }
  }

  public authServiceCallback(error) {
    if (error) {
      // This will cause an error child component to appear
      this.error = error.code;
    } else {
      // Do something else
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
  this.authService.signUp(this.signUp.value.email, this.signUp.value.password, 
      this.authServiceCallback.bind(this));
```

otherwise `this` won't point to the current class instance.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it the arrow-function way:

```
this.authService.signUp(this.signUp.value.email, this.signUp.value.password, x => this.authServiceCallback ( x (or whatever) ) );
```

The arrow funcs make the "this" more predictable.

Format if no arg needed:

```
() => this.authServiceCallback ( )
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm accepting Günter's answer only because it came in a few seconds earlier.